# Has "add polygon attributes to points" been removed from QGIS?

Tags: qgis, spatial-join, qgis-processing

I've been using "add polygon attributes to points" in qgis for a while, but hadn't needed it for a while (@Underdark provided [this](http://anitagraser.com/2013/10/02/add-polygon-attributes-to-points-vs-join-attributes-by-location/)); in 2.13.0 master on ubuntu it seems to be missing from the processing toolbox. Am I missing something? Do I need to install something special?

Comment: Have you installed SAGA for QGIS?
http://sourceforge.net/projects/saga-gis/files/

Comment: thanks, that's the solution. Previous install was windows which installs everything through OSGeo4W, whereas this doesn't happen in Linux. Do you want to post this as an answer so you can get credit for it?

Answer (score 1):

As commented by @crunchbangax you need to install SAGA for QGIS:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/saga-gis/files/